# AWS CLI throws "Unable to locate credentials", the second time it's run

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cli, cloud-init

I'm trying to download some files from S3 to an EC2 instance using the AWS CLI (1.8.7) on startup using a User-Data Script. This instance has a IAM Role & Instance Profile with the appropriate permissions. Sometimes, the CLI will fail with the error "Unable to locate credentials". It happens often, (not every time), but always *after* a separate S3 command, which worked. Here's the output of the script:

```
++ date +%r
03:24:10 AM
++ aws s3 cp s3://non-public-bucket-1/15mb-zip-file.zip ./15mb-zip-file.zip
Completed 1 of 1 part(s) with 1 file(s) remaining^Mdownload: s3://non-public-bucket-1/15mb-zip-file.zip to 15mb-zip-file.zip
++ date +%r
03:24:14 AM
++ unzip 15mb-zip-file.zip

# Snip

++ date +%r
03:26:01 AM
++ curl http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/instance-id
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100    10  100    10    0     0  13831      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:-- 10000
i-12345678++ date +%r
03:26:01 AM
++ aws s3 cp s3://non-public-bucket-2/my-small-text-file.json ./output.json
download failed: s3://non-public-bucket-2/my-small-text-file.json to output.json Unable to locate credentials

++ date +%r
03:26:34 AM
```

Any idea what could cause this?

Edit: This is an Amazon Linux server.

Comment: Have you tried putting a 10 second delay before trying to fetch the files? Perhaps the IAM credentials aren't in place yet the first time the command is run.

Comment: I'm having exactly the same issue with Ubuntu 16.04 LTS.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue, even contacted support and they could not provide an answer. Exporting credentials to environmental variables does not work for `aws s3 ...` commands. You have to either use the `aws configure` util or create a `~/.aws/config` file like this one:

```
[default]
aws_access_key_id=foo
aws_secret_access_key=bar
region=us-west-2
```

Please reference AWS documentation at http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/topic/config-vars.html

Not only did I find it failing to execute at all with the environment exports on EC2 launch via the User Data but also post launch from the command line on a fully deployed running instance.

Comment: What is `~` in this case?  I tried `echo $USER` and `echo $HOME` in my User Data script and both of these variables come out blank.