# AWS CloudFormation - Calling CLI from Init can't get credentials

Tags: amazon-web-services, automation, amazon-cloudformation, aws-cli

I'm using a CloudFormation template to boot up a custom **windows** AMI, which needs to retrieve some code from an S3 bucket and execute it, once it boots up.

After quickly being able to do it manually using the AWS CLI (`s3 sync`) I've been struggling to get this to work via CloudFormation for over 8 hours now, to no avail. In essence, this command always fails with:

> "NoCredentialsError: Unable to locate credentials"

Initially I tried setting the `/.aws/credentials` and `/.aws/config` files, in many different ways, until I finally realized that the user identity running `cfn-init.exe` and it's child processes doesn't have access to these files at all and that won't work. So instead I've opted for setting environment variables using `setx`, but that doesn't seem to work either and I'm still getting the same error.

I'm getting quite frustrated with this as every test requires a change to the CF template, uploading to S3, creating a stack, waiting a good 5-10 minutes for it to finish bootstrapping only to RDP and find out it failed, *again*.

Here's the `init > config` portion of my template:

```
"commands" : {
  "0-Tester" : {
    "command" : "echo \"I am OK.\" > \"d:\\test.txt\""
  },
  "1-SetAK" : {
    "command" : { "Fn::Join" : ["", [
      "setx AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID ",
      { "Ref": "AutomationUserAK" }
    ]] }
  },
  "2-SetSK" : {
    "command" : { "Fn::Join" : ["", [
      "setx AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY ",
      { "Ref": "AutomationUserSK" }
    ]] }
  },
  "3-Pullcode" : {
    "command" : "aws s3 sync s3://some-s3-bucket d:/dev/ --debug"
  }
}
```

The first 3 commands (Tester, SetAK, SetSK) work just fine. The last one (Pullcode) fails, every time.

So at this point I'm assuming I'm going at it wrong. Maybe I need to configure a specific IAM for the CF stack, maybe I should use `setx ... /M`, maybe a million other options, but since this trial and error has been going for the entire length of my work day and then some I figured it won't hurt to ask.

Comment: I saw a similar issue (albeit apparently on Linux) here: https://serverfault.com/questions/731109/aws-cli-throws-unable-to-locate-credentials-the-second-time-its-run?rq=1 and possible a couple others on AWS's forums. Seems like this might actually be a bug, which would mean I have to do some kind of alternative, like putting the code in a ZIP file on a public S3 URL, downloading it with the `files` feature and then unzipping it with a shell command. This is _not_ great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each of your *commands* is run in a separate PowerShell, hence `setx AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID` sets the variable in *one* shell instance and exits. Then `setx AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY` sets another variable in a *new* shell and exits. Then you run `aws s3 sync` in *yet another* shell where none of the previous variables exist and it fails because the credentials variables do not exist in *that* shell.

Instead of calling it from Metadata you can do something like:

```
"UserData": {
  "Fn::Base64": { "Fn::Join": ["", [
    "<script>\n",
    "cfn-init.exe -v -s [...]\n",
    "setx AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID ", { "Ref": "AutomationUserAK" }, "\n",
    "setx AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY ", { "Ref": "AutomationUserSK" }, "\n",
    "aws s3 sync s3://some-s3-bucket d:/dev/\n",
    "</script>"
  ] ] }
}
```

In this case it will all be run in the same shell instance and the keys will be still set when you call `aws s3 sync`.

### Use IAM Roles instead

However I have to say that passing access and secret keys to CloudFormation template is a *bad bad* practice. Instead the CloudFormation template should create **IAM Role** with the appropriate permissions to access the S3 bucket and assign it to the EC2 instance. The `aws` tool on the instance will than have transparent access to S3 without any need to supply access and secret keys. Something like this should do for your CloudFormation template:

First create the **IAM Role** with **S3 access policy** (adjust the policy for your needs):

```
"InstanceRole": {
  "Type": "AWS::IAM::Role",
  "Properties": {
    "AssumeRolePolicyDocument": {
      "Version": "2012-10-17",
      "Statement": [
        {
          "Effect": "Allow",
          "Principal": { "Service": [ "ec2.amazonaws.com" ] },
          "Action": [ "sts:AssumeRole" ]
        }
      ]
    },
    "Path": "/",
    "Policies": [
      { 
        "PolicyName": "S3_Access",
        "PolicyDocument": {
          "Statement": [
            {
              "Effect": "Allow",
              "Action": [ "s3:List*", "s3:Get*" ],
              "Resource": "*"
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
  }
},
```

Then create an **IAM Instance Profile** that refers to the above IAM Role...

```
"InstanceProfile": {
  "Type": "AWS::IAM::InstanceProfile",
  "Properties": {
    "Path": "/",
    "Roles": [ { "Ref": "InstanceRole" }
    ]
  }
},
```

And finally create the EC2 Instance that gets that **IAM Profile** assigned (and in turn **IAM Role** with the S3 access policy).

```
"Instance": {
  "Type": "AWS::EC2::Instance",
  "Properties": {
    "IamInstanceProfile": { "Ref": "InstanceProfile" },
    [...],
    "UserData": {
      "Fn::Base64": { "Fn::Join": ["", [
        "<script>\n",
        "cfn-init.exe -v -s ", { "Ref" : "AWS::StackId" }, " -r Instance --region ", { "Ref" : "AWS::Region" }, "\n",
        "</script>"
      ] ] }
    }
  },
  "Metadata": {
    "AWS::CloudFormation::Init": {
      "config": {
        "commands" : {
          "Pullcode" : {
            "command" : "aws s3 sync s3://some-s3-bucket d:/dev/ --debug"
          }
        }
      } 
    }
  }
},
```

When using *IAM Roles* the *AWS credentials* are dynamically generated and transparently obtained by the `aws` command. This is much more secure and a preferable way to give EC2 instances access to AWS resources.

Learn more about EC2 Instance Roles for example here: https://aws.nz/best-practice/ec2-instance-roles/

Hope that helps :)

Comment: Thanks @MLu - saved again. I had a feeling that passing the keys via CFN templates is a bad idea but I was running out of ideas. This would be the next step to try, but you've cleared up the right way of doing it and it worked. Thanks again!

Comment: @motig88 - I'm always happy to help :) BTW if you're still working on your 3-server setup that we discussed in the other question be aware that you can share the `InstanceRole` and `InstanceProfile` between them. You don't need to create separate ones for each instance.